# propagate event to mother class in nodejs

Tags: node.js, events

in nodejs I have a main that create some objects that will emit events.
One of those is the digitalInput that will be listening the gpio.

The class look like this:

```
class dInput
{
  constructor(port, _id, _name, _messageBus)
  {
    this.gpio = new Gpio(port, {
        mode: Gpio.INPUT,
        pullUpDown: Gpio.PUD_DOWN,
        edge: Gpio.EITHER_EDGE
    });

    this.ID = _id;
    this.Name = _name;
    this.messageBus = _messageBus;

    this.gpio.on('interrupt', function(level){
        var details = {
            ID: this.ID,
            level: level,
            name: this.Name
        };
        DigitalInputsController.ReportChange(details);          
    });

    console.log("created"); 
  }
}
```

The messageBus i a `var messageBus = new events.EventEmitter();` that I create in the main, and I pass to the digitalInput when creating it.

When the value of the gpio changes, the chain of events start properly but what

This is how I listen at the main:

```
messageBus.on("dInputChanged", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit("ButtonStateChanged", data);
});
```

I receive a main level is:

```
{ ID: undefined, level: 0, name: undefined }
```

Any clue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context (`this`) in which event handlers are called is the `EventEmitter` instance itself.

In this particular case, inside the `'interrupt'` event handler on `this.gpio` the context will be `this.gpio`. To instead refer to the `dInput` instance, you will either need to use an arrow function which overrides `this` and sets it to the current context:

```
this.gpio.on('interrupt', (level) => {
    var details = {
        ID: this.ID,
        level: level,
        name: this.Name
    };
    DigitalInputsController.ReportChange(details);          
});
```

or you will need to add a `var self = this;` outside the event handler and use `self.ID`, `self.Name`, etc. in your event handler.

You could also use `eventHandler.bind()` to override `this` inside the event handler, but that is only a fast operation in very recent versions of node (e.g. v7.0.0+).